# Solving inhomogeneous ode with non-constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Do we have an explicit solution up to some constant for inhomogenous ODE with non-constant coefficients?

Comment: Welcome to M.SE! In order to get a satisfaccotry answer, I suggest you to include more details to your answer. For example, what is the motivation of your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes yes, sometimes no.  It depends on the equation.

EDIT: For example, $y'' + y/x^2 = x^2$ has general solution
$$ y = a \sqrt{x} \cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \ln(x)\right) + 
       b  \sqrt{x} \sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \ln(x)\right) + \frac{x^4}{13}$$
for arbitrary constants $a, b$.

Comment: Thank you, could you pls give me one example for having solution

Comment: The example solution doesn't solve the example ODE when $a = b = 0$. I think you may have solved it with an $x^2$ on the right hand side.

Comment: Sorry, yes, that was a typo.